# How to do complex indexing in Python?

Tags: python, matlab, indexing, subset

I have transitioned from Matlab to Python and I am facing issues in indexing/subsetting. I have two dataframes. on is CT and the other is oco. I have to extract the values from oco based on the lat/lon with some margin from the CT dataframe. My Matlab code is working fine but when I try in Python, it is giving different values.

Below is the Matlab code:

```matlab
clc 
clear 

dataleng = [];

myFolderct = '/Users/farhanmustafa/Documents/analysis2/year2012/';

if ~isdir(myFolderct)
  errorMessage = sprintf('Error: The following folder does not exist:\n%s', myFolder);
  uiwait(warndlg(errorMessage));
  return;
end


dategg = [];
 CTall = [];  SXCT = [];   GO1 = []; 

 
myFolder = '/Users/farhanmustafa/Documents/analysis2/gosat2012/';

if ~isdir(myFolder)
  errorMessage = sprintf('Error: The following folder does not exist:\n%s', myFolder);
  uiwait(warndlg(errorMessage));
  return;
end

filePattern = fullfile(myFolder,'*.nc4');
theFiles = dir(filePattern);
dataleng = [dataleng;length(theFiles)];

for k = 1:1
 baseFileName = theFiles(k).name;
 fullFileName = fullfile(myFolder, baseFileName);
 fprintf(1, 'Now reading %s\n', fullFileName);
 
 ncid = netcdf.open(fullFileName,'NC_NOWRITE');
 varid = netcdf.inqVarID(ncid,'longitude');
 lon = netcdf.getVar(ncid,varid);
 
 
 varid = netcdf.inqVarID(ncid,'latitude');
 lat = netcdf.getVar(ncid,varid);
 
  varid = netcdf.inqVarID(ncid,'xco2'); 
  xco2 = netcdf.getVar(ncid,varid);
 
  
  varid = netcdf.inqVarID(ncid,'xco2_uncertainty'); 
  err = netcdf.getVar(ncid,varid);
  
  varid = netcdf.inqVarID(ncid,'xco2_quality_flag'); 
  qflag = netcdf.getVar(ncid,varid);
  qflagd = double(qflag);
  
  varid = netcdf.inqVarID(ncid,'xco2_averaging_kernel'); 
  KA = netcdf.getVar(ncid,varid);
  KAm = flip(KA);
  
  varid = netcdf.inqVarID(ncid,'pressure_levels'); 
  ocopl = netcdf.getVar(ncid,varid);
  ocoplm = flip(ocopl*100);
  
  
   varid = netcdf.inqVarID(ncid,'pressure_weight'); 
  pw = netcdf.getVar(ncid,varid);
  pwm = flip(pw);
  
   varid = netcdf.inqVarID(ncid,'xco2_apriori'); 
  Xa = netcdf.getVar(ncid,varid);
  Xam = Xa';
  
   varid = netcdf.inqVarID(ncid,'co2_profile_apriori'); 
  Pa = netcdf.getVar(ncid,varid);
  Pam = flip(Pa);
    
  
  varid = netcdf.inqVarID(ncid,'time');
  t = netcdf.getVar(ncid,varid);
  t = double(t)/86400 + datenum([1970 01 01 00 00 00]);
 
  [Y,M,D,H,MM,SS] = datevec(double(t)); 
  
 oco = [t,Y,M,D,H,lon,lat,xco2,err, qflagd];
 
 qflag_filter = (oco(:,10)==0);
 
 t = oco(qflag_filter,1);
 Y = oco(qflag_filter,2);
 M = oco(qflag_filter,3);
 D = oco(qflag_filter,4);
 H = oco(qflag_filter,5);
 lon = oco(qflag_filter,6);
 lat = oco(qflag_filter,7);
 xco2 = oco(qflag_filter,8);
 err = oco(qflag_filter,9);
 qflagd = oco(qflag_filter,10);
  
 oco = [t,Y,M,D,H,lon,lat,xco2,err, qflagd];
 

filePatternct = fullfile(myFolderct,'*.nc');
theFilesct = dir(filePatternct);
dataleng = [dataleng;length(theFilesct)];
baseFileNamect = theFilesct(k).name;
fullFileNamect = fullfile(myFolderct, baseFileNamect);
fprintf(1, 'Now reading %s\n', fullFileNamect);
ncid = netcdf.open(fullFileNamect,'NC_NOWRITE');
  
varid = netcdf.inqVarID(ncid,'longitude')  ;
lonct = netcdf.getVar(ncid,varid);
 
varid = netcdf.inqVarID(ncid,'latitude');
latct = netcdf.getVar(ncid,varid);
 
 varid = netcdf.inqVarID(ncid,'co2');
 ct = double(netcdf.getVar(ncid,varid));
  
 varid = netcdf.inqVarID(ncid,'pressure');
 ctgph = double(netcdf.getVar(ncid,varid));
  
 varid = netcdf.inqVarID(ncid,'time');
 tct = netcdf.getVar(ncid,varid);
 datect = double(tct) + datenum([2000 01 01 00 00 00]);
 [Yct,Mct,Dct,HHct] = datevec(double(tct) + datenum([2000 01 01 00 00 00]));
 
 netcdf.close(ncid)
 
 l1 = find(lonct>=28.5 & lonct<=142.5);
 l2 = find(latct>=-7 & latct<=55);
CT =[];
CTgph = [];
load /Users/farhanmustafa/Documents/MATLAB/grid_arrengiment_index2.mat
  for ii = 1:3:23
   ih = find(HHct==ii); 
 ct1 = ct(l1,l2,1,ih); ct2 = ct(l1,l2,2,ih);ct3 = ct(l1,l2,3,ih);
ct4 = ct(l1,l2,4,ih);ct5 = ct(l1,l2,5,ih);ct6 = ct(l1,l2,6,ih);
ct7 = ct(l1,l2,7,ih);ct8 = ct(l1,l2,8,ih);ct9 = ct(l1,l2,9,ih);
 ct10 = ct(l1,l2,10,ih);ct11 = ct(l1,l2,11,ih);ct12 = ct(l1,l2,12,ih);
ct13 = ct(l1,l2,13,ih);ct14 = ct(l1,l2,14,ih);ct15 = ct(l1,l2,15,ih);
ct16 = ct(l1,l2,16,ih);ct17 = ct(l1,l2,17,ih);ct18 = ct(l1,l2,18,ih);
 ct19 = ct(l1,l2,19,ih);ct20 = ct(l1,l2,20,ih);ct21 = ct(l1,l2,21,ih);
ct22 = ct(l1,l2,22,ih);ct23 = ct(l1,l2,23,ih);ct24 = ct(l1,l2,24,ih);
ct25 = ct(l1,l2,25,ih);

    gph1 = ctgph(l1,l2,1,ih);gph2 = ctgph(l1,l2,2,ih);gph3 = ctgph(l1,l2,3,ih);
gph4 = ctgph(l1,l2,4,ih);gph5 = ctgph(l1,l2,5,ih);gph6 = ctgph(l1,l2,6,ih);
gph7 = ctgph(l1,l2,7,ih);gph8 = ctgph(l1,l2,8,ih);gph9 = ctgph(l1,l2,9,ih);
 gph10 = ctgph(l1,l2,10,ih);gph11 = ctgph(l1,l2,11,ih);gph12 = ctgph(l1,l2,12,ih);
gph13 = ctgph(l1,l2,13,ih);gph14 = ctgph(l1,l2,14,ih);gph15 = ctgph(l1,l2,15,ih);
gph16 = ctgph(l1,l2,16,ih);gph17 = ctgph(l1,l2,17,ih);gph18 = ctgph(l1,l2,18,ih);
 gph19 = ctgph(l1,l2,19,ih);gph20 = ctgph(l1,l2,20,ih);gph21 = ctgph(l1,l2,21,ih);
gph22 = ctgph(l1,l2,22,ih);gph23 = ctgph(l1,l2,23,ih);gph24 = ctgph(l1,l2,24,ih);
gph25 = ctgph(l1,l2,25,ih);



 lonaf= lonct(l1);lataf = latct(l2);
  
ct1 = ct1(:);ct2 = ct2(:);ct3 = ct3(:);ct4 = ct4(:);ct5 = ct5(:);
ct6 = ct6(:);ct7 = ct7(:);ct8 = ct8(:);ct9 = ct9(:);ct10 = ct10(:);
ct11 = ct11(:);ct12 = ct12(:);ct13 = ct13(:);ct14 = ct14(:);ct15 = ct15(:);
ct16 = ct16(:);ct17 = ct17(:);ct18 = ct18(:);ct19 = ct19(:);ct20 = ct20(:);
ct21 = ct21(:);ct22 = ct22(:);ct23 = ct23(:);ct24 = ct24(:);ct25 = ct25(:);
f = ~isnan(gph1);
gph1 = gph1(:);gph2 = gph2(:);gph3 = gph3(:);gph4 = gph4(:);gph5 = gph5(:);
gph6 = gph6(:);gph7 = gph7(:);gph8 = gph8(:);gph9 = gph9(:);gph10 = gph10(:);
gph11 = gph11(:);gph12 = gph12(:);gph13 = gph13(:);gph14 = gph14(:);gph15 = gph15(:);
gph16 = gph16(:);gph17 = gph17(:);gph18 = gph18(:);gph19 = gph19(:);gph20 = gph20(:);
gph21 = gph21(:);gph22 = gph22(:);gph23 = gph23(:);gph24 = gph24(:);gph25 = gph25(:);


 [n,m,] = find(f==1);
 
  yy = [];
 for ii = 1:length(n)
 yy = [yy;datect(ih),Yct(ih),Mct(ih),Dct(ih),HHct(ih)];
 end

CT = [CT;yy(1:length(n),:),lonaf(n),lataf(m),ct1,ct2,ct3,ct4,ct5,ct6,ct7,ct8...
    ,ct9,ct10,ct11,ct12,ct13,ct14,ct15,ct16,ct17,ct18,ct19,ct20,ct21,ct22,ct23,ct24,ct25];

CTgph = [CTgph;yy(1:length(n),:),lonaf(n),lataf(m),gph1,gph2,gph3,gph4,gph5,gph6,gph7,gph8...
    ,gph9,gph10,gph11,gph12,gph13,gph14,gph15,gph16,gph17,gph18,gph19,gph20,gph21,gph22,gph23,gph24,gph25];

  
  end
  CTall = [CTall;CT];
 
  
di = CT(:,1); ilon = CT(:,6); ilat=CT(:,7);
gd= oco(:,1); glon = oco(:,6); glat=oco(:,7);

for ii = 1:length(CT)
    
    indx = find(glon(:)<=(ilon(ii)+1.5) & glon(:)>=(ilon(ii)-1.5) & ...
                glat(:)<=(ilat(ii)+1.5) & glat(:)>=(ilat(ii)-1.5));
            
          if indx~=0
              
            
             GO1 = [GO1;oco(indx,:)];
                
  end  
    
end


end
```

and the Python code is given in the following:

```py
import os
import glob
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr
from datetime import datetime as dt
from datetime import timedelta
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import re

def find_files_in_dir(path, substrs):   
    file_list = []
    for root, directory, files in os.walk(path):
        for f in files:
            for s in substrs:
                if s in f:
                    file_list.append(os.path.join(root, f))

    file_list.sort()
    return file_list

myFolder = '/Users/farhanmustafa/Documents/analysis2/gosat2012/'
sat_substrs = ['.nc4']
myFolderct = '/Users/farhanmustafa/Documents/analysis2/year2012/'
ct_substrs = ['.nc']
sat_file_list = find_files_in_dir(myFolder, sat_substrs)
ct_file_list = find_files_in_dir(myFolderct, ct_substrs)

CTall = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(*[]))).add_prefix('Col')
GO1 = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(*[]))).add_prefix('Col')
for i in range(len(sat_file_list)):
    print("Reading", sat_file_list[i])
    ds = xr.open_dataset(sat_file_list[i])
    ds = ds.swap_dims({'sounding_id': 'time'})
    lon_sat = ds.longitude.values.tolist()
    lat_sat = ds.latitude.values.tolist()
    xco2 = ds.xco2.values.tolist()
    err = ds.xco2_uncertainty.values.tolist()
    qflag = ds.xco2_quality_flag.values.tolist()
    KA = ds.xco2_averaging_kernel
    KAm = np.flip(KA, 0)
    ocopl = ds.pressure_levels
    ocoplm = np.flip((ocopl*100), 0)
    pw = ds.pressure_weight
    pwm = np.flip(pw)
    Xa = ds.xco2_apriori
    Xam = Xa.T
    Pa = ds.co2_profile_apriori
    time_sat = ds.time.values.tolist()
    time_sat = pd.to_datetime(time_sat)

    oco = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(*[time_sat, lon_sat, lat_sat, xco2, err, qflag]))).add_prefix('Col')
    ds.close()
    
    print("Reading", ct_file_list[i])
    ds = xr.open_dataset(ct_file_list[i])
    longitude=slice(28.5, 142.5)
    latitude=slice(-7, 55)
    ct = ds.co2.sel(longitude=longitude, latitude=latitude)
    ctgph = ds.pressure
    #time = ds.time.dt.hour[7]
    #time = time.time.values
    #ct_df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(*[]))).add_prefix('Col')
    CT = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(*[]))).add_prefix('Col')
    #gph_df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(*[]))).add_prefix('Col')
    CTgph = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(*[]))).add_prefix('Col')
    for i in [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]:
        time = ds.time.dt.hour[i]
        time = time.time.values

        ct1 = (ct.sel(level=1)).isel(time=i).values.flatten()
        ct2 = (ct.sel(level=2)).isel(time=i).values.flatten()
        ct3 = (ct.sel(level=3)).isel(time=i).values.flatten()
        ct4 = (ct.sel(level=4)).isel(time=i).values.flatten()
        ct5 = (ct.sel(level=5)).isel(time=i).values.flatten()
        ct6 = (ct.sel(level=6)).isel(time=i).values.flatten()
        ct7 = (ct.sel(level=7)).isel(time=i).values.flatten()
        ct8 = (ct.sel(level=8)).isel(time=i).values.flatten()
        ct9 = (ct.sel(level=9)).isel(time=i).values.flatten()
        ct10 = (ct.sel(level=10)).isel(time=i).values.flatten()
        ct11 = (ct.sel(level=11)).isel(time=i).values.flatten()
        ct12 = (ct.sel(level=12)).isel(time=i).values.flatten()
        ct13 = (ct.sel(level=13)).isel(time=i).values.flatten()
        ct14 = (ct.sel(level=14)).isel(time=i).values.flatten()
        ct15 = (ct.sel(level=15)).isel(time=i).values.flatten()
        ct16 = (ct.sel(level=16)).isel(time=i).values.flatten()
        ct17 = (ct.sel(level=17)).isel(time=i).values.flatten()
        ct18 = (ct.sel(level=18)).isel(time=i).values.flatten()
        ct19 = (ct.sel(level=19)).isel(time=i).values.flatten()
        ct20 = (ct.sel(level=20)).isel(time=i).values.flatten()
        ct21 = (ct.sel(level=21)).isel(time=i).values.flatten()
        ct22 = (ct.sel(level=22)).isel(time=i).values.flatten()
        ct23 = (ct.sel(level=23)).isel(time=i).values.flatten()
        ct24 = (ct.sel(level=24)).isel(time=i).values.flatten()
        ct25 = (ct.sel(level=25)).isel(time=i).values.flatten()
        
        gph1 = (ctgph.sel(boundary=1)).isel(time=i).values.flatten()
        gph2 = (ctgph.sel(boundary=2)).isel(time=i).values.flatten()
        gph3 = (ctgph.sel(boundary=3)).isel(time=i).values.flatten()
        gph4 = (ctgph.sel(boundary=4)).isel(time=i).values.flatten()
        gph5 = (ctgph.sel(boundary=5)).isel(time=i).values.flatten()
        gph6 = (ctgph.sel(boundary=6)).isel(time=i).values.flatten()
        gph7 = (ctgph.sel(boundary=7)).isel(time=i).values.flatten()
        gph8 = (ctgph.sel(boundary=8)).isel(time=i).values.flatten()
        gph9 = (ctgph.sel(boundary=9)).isel(time=i).values.flatten()
        gph10 = (ctgph.sel(boundary=10)).isel(time=i).values.flatten()
        gph11 = (ctgph.sel(boundary=11)).isel(time=i).values.flatten()
        gph12 = (ctgph.sel(boundary=12)).isel(time=i).values.flatten()
        gph13 = (ctgph.sel(boundary=13)).isel(time=i).values.flatten()
        gph14 = (ctgph.sel(boundary=14)).isel(time=i).values.flatten()
        gph15 = (ctgph.sel(boundary=15)).isel(time=i).values.flatten()
        gph16 = (ctgph.sel(boundary=16)).isel(time=i).values.flatten()
        gph17 = (ctgph.sel(boundary=17)).isel(time=i).values.flatten()
        gph18 = (ctgph.sel(boundary=18)).isel(time=i).values.flatten()
        gph19 = (ctgph.sel(boundary=19)).isel(time=i).values.flatten()
        gph20 = (ctgph.sel(boundary=20)).isel(time=i).values.flatten()
        gph21 = (ctgph.sel(boundary=21)).isel(time=i).values.flatten()
        gph22 = (ctgph.sel(boundary=22)).isel(time=i).values.flatten()
        gph23 = (ctgph.sel(boundary=23)).isel(time=i).values.flatten()
        gph24 = (ctgph.sel(boundary=24)).isel(time=i).values.flatten()
        gph25 = (ctgph.sel(boundary=25)).isel(time=i).values.flatten()

        listOfStrings2 = [time]*len(ct1)
        
        lonct = ct.longitude.values.tolist()
        latct = ct.latitude.values.tolist()

        
        lonct = [a for a in lonct  
          for b in latct if a != b] 

        latct = [b for a in lonct  
          for b in latct if a != b] 

        CT2 = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(*[listOfStrings2,lonct,latct,ct1,ct2,ct3,ct4,ct5,ct6,ct7,ct8,ct9,ct10,ct11,ct12,ct13,ct14,ct15,ct16,ct17,ct18,ct19,ct20,ct21,ct22,ct23,ct24,ct25]))).add_prefix('Col')
        CTgph = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(*[listOfStrings2,lonct,latct,gph1,gph2,gph3,gph4,gph5,gph6,gph7,gph8,gph9,gph10,gph11,gph12,gph13,gph14,gph15,gph16,gph17,gph18,gph19,gph20,gph21,gph22,gph23,gph24,gph25]))).add_prefix('Col')
        #gph_df = gph_df.append(gph_df2)
        CT = CT.append(CT2)
        ds.close()
    CTall = CTall.append(CT)
    
    
    di = CT.Col0
    ilon = CT.Col1
    ilat = CT.Col2
    sat_date = oco.Col0
    sat_lon = oco.Col1
    sat_lat = oco.Col2
    

    for ii in range(len(CT)):
        subset = oco[(ilat[ii]<=(sat_lat[:]+1.5)) & (ilat[ii]>=(sat_lat[:]-1.5)) & 
                         (ilon[ii]<=(sat_lon[:]+1.5)) & (ilon[ii]>=(sat_lon[:]-1.5))]
    
        GO1 = GO1.append(subset)
```

Please note that data frames are the same in both cases. I will be thankful in someone helps me in sorting out this.

Comment: Surely the first problem is that that python is invalid due to the bad indentation

Comment: The next problem is that `list.append()` returns `None`. `GO1 = GO1.append(subset)` sets `GO1` to `None` after the first iteration. Is that what you mean by _giving different values_?

Comment: @AnderBiguri, thank you for your help. Sir, the indentation was no issue. I tried to write the part of code which was creating an issue, so it was a writing mistake by me which was showing the indentation issue. Now I have updated the code in the question and written the whole code. Please note that the outputs are the same till ` CTall = CTall.append(CT) `. The problem is being created after indexing.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi, Thank you sir for your kind reply. I think the way I was asking the question was confusing. I have updated the code in the question, which, I think is more understandable. Please have a look at the code now.

Comment: Please read [mre]. I'm sure you can reduce the size of your code for the purpose of this question. Nobody is going to read and try to understand that much code.